# The art of interpolation over a subset of multiple-dimensions (c++)

Tags: c++, performance, function, interpolation

I have been looking for an answer to this for quite a while, but I am not able to find one.

#### The problem:

I have a n-dimensional (e.g. n = 9) function which is extremely computationally burdensome to evaluate, but for which I need a huge amount of evaluations. I want to use interpolation for this case.

However k < n dimensions (e.g. k = 7) are discrete (mostly binary) and therefore I need **not** to interpolate over these, which leaves me with m-dimensions (e.g. 2) over which I want to interpolate. I am mostly interested in basic linear interpolation, similar to http://rncarpio.github.io/linterp/.

#### The question:

(**Option A**) Should I invoke d1 x d2 x ... x dk interpolation functions (e.g. 2^7= 128) which then only interpolate over the two dimensions I need, but I need to look for the right interpolation function every time I need a value, ...

... (**Option B**) or should I invoke one interpolation function which could possible interpolate between all dimensions, but which I then will only use to interpolate across the two dimensions I need (for all others I fully provide the grid with function values)?

I think it is important to  emphasize that I am really interested in linear interpolation and that the answer will most likely differ in other cases. Furthermore, in the application I want to use this, I need not 128 functions but rather over 10,000 functions.

Additionally, should option A be the answer, how should I store the interpolation functions in c++, i.e. should I use a map with a tuple as a key (drawing on the boost library), or a multidimensional array (again, drawing on the boost library) or is there an easier way?

Comment: post some code, or even some pseudo-code, or something. we're not clairvoyant.

Answer (score 0):

I'd likely choose Option A, but not maps. If you have binary data, just use an array of size 2 (this is one of the rare cases when using an array is right); if you have a small domain consider having two vectors, one for keys, one for values. This is because vector search can be made extremely efficient on at least on x86 / x64 architectures. Be sure to hide this implementation detail by providing an accessor function (i.e., `const value& T::lookup(const key&)`). I'd vote against using a tuple as a map key as it makes it both slower and more complicated. If you need to extremely optimize and your domains are so small that the product of their cardinality fits within 64 bits, you might just manually create an index key (like: (1<<3) * key4bits + (1<<2) * keyBinary + key2bits), in this case you'll use a map (or two vectors).

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I find this answer very appealing. However, I think I have not fully understood, how to use your idea of storing the keys in a vector and using another vector for values without using a map.

I try to figure it out over the next couple of days and then will get back to this.

Comment: I still have my trouble understanding how you would set up the vectors. It would be great if you could post some code or a link to understand what you propose.